Android app that plays a sound on notification on silent and DND mode
I have installed an emergency application on my android phone, that rings even if DND mode is on and silent mode is on.
When the app was installed the only permission it requested was to sent me notification. And that is the only permission available.
My question is:
Is there a hack I don't know about to play a notification sound (when the application is in the background), When the user is in DND mode or silent?
I've tried:
   notificationChannel.setBypassDnd(true);

Didn't work.
SDK version 34

If the application is running in the background (e.g., it has a foreground service), it could simply play the sound directly, using MediaPlayer or equivalents.

even in silent/ DND mode?

Ah, sorry, I was thinking of the user muting notifications themselves, not device-wide DND mode.
